# How to process a twig template without displaying it in Silex

Tags: twig, silex

Just a quick question:

In Silex, if I want to grab the output of a twig template, without displaying it so as to do more processing on the outcome (adding more filters, saving to a file), how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use twig `render` method that will return output for processed template

```
$output = $app['twig']->render('path/to/template', $vars);
```